# Web speech API for speech to text on Android chrome browser

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, webspeech-api

I am trying speech to text conversion in reactjs web application using [Web speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API) .
When I open application on Windows desktop, web speech API works without any problem.
But when I open the same application on Android chrome browser, it recognizes the same speech multiple times. I think on android chrome browser, the intermediate results of web speech API are considered as final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition.

The transcript contains duplicate words!
There is a bug in Android Chrome that causes the Web Speech API to generate duplicate words in the speech recognition result. Possible workarounds:

Set the continuous option to false (This worked in my case)
Detect Android Chrome and render fallback content on that browser

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem.  What I load my app, I check for to determine if the app is loaded on a mobile device and set a non displayable (your option) checkbox within the html file, as follows:

```
x_mobileFlg = window.navigator.userAgentData.mobile
gObj_deviceFlgs.mobileDevice = x_mobileFlg
if (x_mobileFlg) {
    document.getElementById("chkbox-mobile-device").checked = true
}
else {
    document.getElementById("chkbox-mobile-device").checked = false
}
```

Then when I initiate the speech recongition api call I change the continuous flag if the device is mobile.

```
objVoiceRecognitionInput.continuous = true
if (document.getElementById("chkbox-mobile-device").checked) {
    objVoiceRecognitionInput.continuous = false;
}
```

This worked perfectly, and I can input the text I want with my voice on either device.